# Form paint event doesn't paint properly when using vertical scroll

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that accepts data and depending on what data is entered it will open up another form and draw images that I have included in their appropriate spots. I have succeeded in this. I have limited the amount of horizontal space its allowed to draw in so once it reaches a certain point it starts drawing below the previous images until the code tells it not to draw anything else.

The problem I am having is I want to be able to draw an unlimited amount of images vertically and use a vertical scroll bar to see the images below if they are cut off. What is happening is when I scroll down slow, the images don't get drawn it's almost like they are cut off. If I scroll down fast i see everything drawn but its all mashed up together. I would like it to act much like using this textbox that I am typing in right now to write this question, once this textbox is filled up to capacity, the scroll bar gets larger and I can then scroll back up or down to see the rest of the content. This form isn't resizable and that is how I would like to keep it.

I am not sure what part of my code to include because everything is drawn properly and in the right spots, it is just when I scroll up or down is when the problem happens.

All of my drawing code is in the form paint event. I draw with e.Graphics.DrawImage() and the images are taken from a file that I have created.

I have set these properties:

```
// on the form 

this.AutoScroll = true 

// after everything has been painted and inside the paint event

this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(totalHeightOfDrawnImages, widthOfForm)
```

Suggestions? I've looked at a lot of links on here and either I don't understand the suggestion for fixing it and have not been able to make it work when it does or they just simply don't work for my situation.

Comment: You are forgetting to call e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(), pass the AutoScrollPosition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PictureBox renders fine than Form.

Adjust your form's height and scrolling borders as it is.

Put a PictureBox control to your form.

Adjust the size of pictureBox to include all your content.

Migrate the Paint event of the Form to the PictureBox.

Comment: The totalHeightOfDrawnImages will be a different height each time the form is created. So do I set the size of the picture box to the total height each time the form is created?

Comment: This worked. I put everything in a PictureBox and migrated everything from the paint event of the form to the PictureBox. It now draws everything and the scrolling does not effect what has been drawn.